# C: trouble understanding this files/struct based instruction

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, record

I'm trying to create a program that will ask the user to enter a name(it is assumed that every name will be 30 characters in length or less). It will then find the popularity of the name between 1921 and 2010 and print out a chart and graph. The program will then ask the user if they wish to do another analysis and repeat the process.

There are about 7 different functions that need to be used for this program, but I'm having trouble understanding 2 of the functions that I need to use.

Function 1:

```
int getRawData(FILE* fp,struct NameRecord records[],int currSize);`
```

> function is passed a pointer to a file that is already open for
>   reading. Each line in this file will be of the form (the names are
>   fully capitalized in the file):
>
> year,NAME,frequency
>
> The function is also passed an array of NameRecord structs (records)
>   and the number of records currently in that array (currSize). this
>   function will read the data from the file into the array placing it at
>   the end of the array (first record from file will be placed into
>   array[currSize]). Function will return total number of records in the
>   array after reading in the file.

```
  struct NameRecord{
          char name[31];
          int year;
          int frequency;
        }
```

Now I'm not sure if this means that I need to create a new array within the function that receives the records from the file or if it's something else entirely and I'm not reading the instructions correctly.(the file in this case is malebabynames.csv)

2nd function:

```
void setYearTotals(struct NameRecord records[], int size, int yearRangeTotal[]);
```

> function is passed an array of NameRecords (records) and the size of
>   that array (size). It is also passed an array called yearRangeTotal
>   which will be used to store the total population for a given year
>   range.
>
> ```
> yearRangeTotal[0] holds the total population between 1921 to 1925
> yearRangeTotal[1] holds the total population between 1926 to 1930
> yearRangeTotal[2] holds the total population between 1931 to 1935
> ...
> yearRangeTotal[17] holds the total population between 2006 to 2010
> ```

Answer (score 1):

(1) No, just fill in the array that is passed.  This isn't different than passing `fread` an array of char (or anything else) and asking it to read N items.  Check the return code to know how many were actually read.

(2) Less clear. I would guess you are being asked to iterate through the NameRecord array and increment the appropriate yearRangeTotal element based on the "year" field in NameRecord.year.